# jQuery autocompletion event

Tags: jquery, events, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I try to develop my first MVC3 application, but there are problems including a jQuery autocompletion select event. When selecting an item, nothing happens. No error, no message. I've used the search function to solve the problem, but there was no working solution for me.

Here's my Razor View Code including the javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete('@Url.Action("Search")', {
        width: 200,
        matchContains: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('event');
        },
        delay: 10,
        minChars: 3,
        matchSubset: 1,
        maxItemsToShow: 10,
        parse: function (data) 
               {
                   var rows = new Array();
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                   {
                       rows[i] = { data: data[i].Value, value: data[i].Guid, result: data[i].Value 
                   };
               }
               return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row, i, n) 
                    {
                        return row;
                    },
        highlight: function (value, pattern) 
                   {
                       value = value.replace(pattern, '<strong style="background-color:yellow;">' + pattern + '</strong>');
                       return value;
                   },
        select: function (value, data)
               { 
                   alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); 
               },
        extraParams: {
            active: function () 
                    {
                        var message = new Array();
                        for (i = 0; i < document.forms["filter"].filters.length; i++)
                            if (document.forms["filter"].filters[i].checked) 
                            {
                                message[i] = document.forms["filter"].filters[i].value;
                            }
                        return message;
                    }
                }

        });
        });
```

Following libraries are used:

```
* Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js 15 2009-08-22 10:30:27Z joern.zaefferer $

* jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.1
```

May someone help me, please?

Comment: did you checked the firebug console to see if any requests are being made? or any errors??

Comment: Try using the official jQueryUI autocomplete widget. The one you're using has been deprecated in favor for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Autocomplete widget in jQuery.UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

There's also an interesting article on how to use it with ASP.NET (not MVC, but close enough):

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515